# How can I launch more than one debug session in Eclipse from a single click?

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I'm currently writing a GWT application through Eclipse. Eclipse is used for development but I use the m2eclipse plugin and a Maven pom.xml with the GWT plugin to build & run it.

When I need to debug the app I must:

1. Invoke "Run As ..." on a Maven project (via m2eclipse) "war:exploded gwt:debug". This launches GWT's app server and waits for a remote debug connection on port 3408. The need to wait for the WAR to be exploded means it could be a minute for this to happen.
2. Invoke "Debug As..." a Remote Java Application to connect to the server.

I've already added both targets to favourites to lock them into the drop down but it's still a pain.

I'd like to launch them both in sequence from a single click rather than two discrete actions.

Is there any way in Eclipse to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this plugin. http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/escripts

You can define scripts of Eclipse actions easily. You create a script of starting the 2 debug session, then run with one click or shortcut.

EDIT:
The plugin was moved and is now called EASE.

https://eclipse.org/ease/

Answer (score 1):

"Launch Groups" are part of the CDT. Officially supported, easy to install.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11905444/518491

Answer (score 0):

Why are you launching like this? Can't you just launch it by GWT plugin? Go to `Run Configurations` -> `Web Application` (the blue circle with "g" inside) and create new Run Configuration.

In it, in Main tab, enter (or select) your project, and enter `com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode` in Main class.

In Arguments enter `-remoteUI "${gwt_remote_ui_server_port}:${unique_id}" -logLevel INFO -port 8888  -war path_to_your_dir_with_WEB-INF_directory com.package.your.Module`

Comment: I don't have a choice in the matter. Our project is extremely large, has a lot of dependencies, pulls in some J2EE and we use Maven to build and manage it. The plugin is okay for smallish projects but not suitable for us.

Comment: If so, I'm afraid it is not possible to launch two debug sessions with one click. AFAIK you can make GWT run on external server, maybe this is a solution, but I don't know how to do it.