# Workspace Editor Macros in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, macros, automation, text-editor

Is there a way to record permanent workspace macros in Eclipse and assign them a shortcut key or template?

I'd like to automate some of the actions I routinely do. Workspace editor templates are not a solution since I need to include some conditional logic as well. For example check what is a symbol to the right/left of the cursor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my answer at [How can I launch more than one debug session in Eclipse from a single click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700265/how-can-i-launch-more-than-one-debug-session-in-eclipse-from-a-single-click/3767695#3767695) . The same plugin can work for you as well.