# Is it possible to script Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I would like to script certain eclipse actions that are too repetitive. An example use case would be: Starting Tomcat, Starting GWT debug, then connecting to GWT debug mode. Best case scenario is if this could be done by shell via an external eclipse interface. But I'd settle for a macro in Eclipse itself as well. Are there any solutions as such?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my answer at [How can I launch more than one debug session in Eclipse from a single click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700265/how-can-i-launch-more-than-one-debug-session-in-eclipse-from-a-single-click/3767695#3767695) . The same plugin can work for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is a little [macro plug-in for Eclipse](http://sourceforge.net/projects/practicalmacro/) that seems to work for what you'd want.