# Is there a way to create an action in eclipse to export my jar to a certain directory?

Tags: eclipse, build

Is there someone to configure a one click or one key action to export my build product to a certain directory? I'm coming from Visual Studio where I can set the output directory and press <kbd>F6</kbd> to do this.

Answer (score 3):

You can right click on project. Export... Then click on Java/Jar file and next. You will se something like this. Specify output filename, and on the next screen click on save description ( see pictures below ). Then after you saved jardesc to the project root, right click and "Create JAR" command. Two click, not one (if you check overwrite in first screen). If you want to automate with a shortcut, try [the plugin in this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700265/how-can-i-launch-more-than-one-debug-session-in-eclipse-from-a-single-click/3767695#3767695)

[image]

[image]